# PowerMock & Mockito seems to be unable to mock static fields soon enough

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock, powermockito

I'm currently trying to introduce unit testing on our project in order to test interaction with an API we are given. Unfortunately the API is quite old and ugly and contains weird things (such as implementation) :-(. In our code we use let's say objects of class A.

```
public class A {
     static B b = new B();
     public int foo(){return 666;}
}
```

As you can see this class contains a static field b that is filled with a new instance of class B on it's initialization. However the construction of class B is not possible in the testing environment. It somehow works only in production environment. Let's simulate it by something like this.

```
public class B {
    B(){
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

In my tests I need to test interaction of my code with class A as this is my contract to the API and contains also some useful methods (foo() in this case). However I'm failing even on the mocking of the instance.

Here is what I tried.

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({A.class,B.class})
public class ATest {

    @Mock
    A a;

    @Mock
    B b;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(b);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeCorrectlyInitialized() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(A.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(a);
        A shouldBeMock = new A();
        Assert.assertEquals(a,shouldBeMock);
    }
}
```

But it seems to me that definition of mocking class B instantiation is way too late in @BeforeClass (and I have no clue how to do it sooner) as the b field is assigned when @PrepareForTest annotation is being applied (which is obviously before the @BeforeClass method is executed) and thus the "real" constructor is used.

Do you have some idea how to overcome this issue?

Finally here is the stacktrace of my test execution

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor6.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.ObjenesisInstantiator.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiator.java:14)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:149)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:64)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(DefaultMockCreator.java:121)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.createMock(DefaultMockCreator.java:69)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.DefaultMockCreator.mock(DefaultMockCreator.java:46)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:201)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:118)
    at org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:63)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:308)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:121)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at s.a.B.<init>(B.java:7)
    at s.a.A.<clinit>(A.java:10)
    ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried already to create your mocks yourself, instead of relying on `@PrepareForTest`

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
//@PrepareForTest({A.class,B.class})
public class ATest {

    //@Mock
    A a = PowerMockito.mock(A.class);

    //@Mock
    B b = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(b);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldBeCorrectlyInitialized() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(A.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(a);
        A shouldBeMock = new A();
        Assert.assertEquals(a,shouldBeMock);
    }
}
```

I think this could help you, but I did not try your code.